# Proof $\det(T - \lambda I_v) = \det([T]_{\beta} - \lambda I) $

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ where $\beta$ is a basis for $V$ and $V$ is finite dimensional.

Proof $\det(T - \lambda I_v) = \det([T]_{\beta} - \lambda I) $

I claimed that $T$ and $[T]_\beta$ are isomorphic thus there characteristic polynomials must be equivalent. I don't see any other loops to jump through to proof the equality.